# Readmore in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to use readmore.js inside a bootstrap carousel. It is working on the first slide but not working on following slides.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('article').readmore({
            moreLink: '<a href="#">[ + ]</a>',
            lessLink: '<a href="#">[ - ]</a>',
            collapsedHeight: 30,
            speed:500,
        });

    });
```

Example :

http://jsfiddle.net/gXN2u/136/

Any idea why this functionality is not working on the remaining slides?

Answer (score 3):

You're invoking the `readmore()` function at document ready and therefore it acts only on the visible element. The simplest fix is to run it every time the carousel displays a new tab, using events, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/oympgthw/

There is a however a [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) as the overflow is applied only after the div is visible (this is how readmore works), so you initially see all the text and then it is shortened. A better approach is to cut text before it is displayed but in this case I guess readmore is not up to the task. Anyway it should be easy to start with the text on a div with fixed height and `overflow: hidden` and put the button to expand it if necessary.